# What is the difference between .one() and .first()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

What is the difference between `one` and `first` methods in SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`Query.one()` requires that there is only *one* result in the result set; it is an error if the database returns 0 or 2 or more results and an exception will be raised.

`Query.first()` returns the first of a potentially larger result set (adding `LIMIT 1` to the query), or `None` if there were no results. No exception will be raised.

From the documentation for [`Query.one()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one):

> Return exactly one result **or raise an exception.**

and from [`Query.first()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first):

> **Return the first result of this Query or None** if the result doesn’t contain any row.

(emphasis mine).

In terms of a Python list, `one()` would be:

```
def one(lst):
    if not lst:
        raise NoResultFound
    if len(lst) > 1:
        raise MultipleResultsFound
    return lst[0]
```

while `first()` would be:

```
def first(lst):
    return lst[0] if lst else None
```

There is also a [`Query.one_or_none()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one_or_none) method, which raises an exception only if there are multiple results for the query. Otherwise it'll return the single result, or `None` if there were no results.

In list terms, that'd be the equivalent of:

```
def one_or_none(lst):
    if not lst:
        return None
    if len(lst) > 1:
        raise MultipleResultsFound
    return lst[0]
```

Comment: I think `first` might use `LIMIT` in the query while `one` doesn't, which might mean that `first` causes subqueries for joins, while `one` would not. This could be a very relevant reason to use `one`.

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand yes, `first()` slices, which is automatically translated to a `LIMIT`. The linked documentation explicitly states `LIMIT` is used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it safe to say that `.one()` is the most efficient/cost-effective way to check if a record simply exists as Halvor Holsten Strand suggests? Because in reading the documentation for `.one()`, `.first()`, and `.one_or_none()` they all state "Calling [the method] results in an execution of the underlying query.", so that leads me to believe that they're essentially equivalent performance-wise as that seems to indicate they all inevitably execute the query (and assumedly the joins).

Comment: Any reason why `one()` is faster than `first()`?

Comment: @Roel: how do you know it is faster? Have you tried running them in the opposite order? Your database results are likely cached by the first version you tried. Performance metrics on such queries, in an ORM, are going to be dependent on a huge number of factors, including if this is on a mapped class or on a core SQL statement object, and what you did previously with the object.