# flask-sqlalchemy - User Query 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: python, authentication, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Python and Flask.

I'm following this tutorial http://douglasstarnes.com/index.php/2015/05/27/easy-authentication-with-flask-login/ to have registration and login pages and have slightly modified it to hash the passwords on registration and to verify the password against the hash on login.

Initial password registration hashing works, but verifying the hashed password stored in the database against the one given in plain text via a login form does not.

The error I am receiving is against the following line on /login page and for the following reason:

```
if user.count() == 1 and check_password_hash(user.password, password) == True:

AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'password'
```

I cannot work out why I'm receiving this error. The user gets successfully queried from the database, and the user has it's hashed password within the password column.

The query I'm using and method of returning data from the password column are similar to that included in the documentation http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/queries/#querying-records

This is my views.py (/login and the erroring line are towards the bottom)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, abort, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from app import app
import os

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.String)

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id)
    if user.count() == 1:
    return user.one()
    return None

@app.before_first_request
def init_request():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/secret')
@login_required
def secret():
    return render_template('secret.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('register.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['txtUsername']
    password = request.form['txtPassword']
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username)
    if user.count() == 0:
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)
        user = User(username=username, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        flash('You have registered the username {0}. Please login'.format(username))
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        flash('The username {0} is already in use.  Please try a new username.'.format(username))
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    else:
    abort(405)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('login.html', next=request.args.get('next'))
    elif request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['txtUsername']
    password = request.form['txtPassword']
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username)
    if user.count() == 1 and check_password_hash(user.password, password) == True:
        login_user(user.one(), remember=True)
        flash('Welcome back {0}'.format(username))
        try:
            next = request.form['next']
            return redirect(next)
        except:
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        flash('Invalid login')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
    return abort(405)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Does anyone know why I cannot access the password column for the user, or in fact any column? I've tried all 3 within the database, ID, username and password.

Comment: user is not the user object itself but only the query. To get the single user use: `user.one()`. This will also raise if more than one user was found.

Comment: If you look at the @login_manager.user_loader he is returning `user.one()` if there is a `user.count() ==1`. I think there is a missing else statement for the return one in that decorator.

Comment: This is of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161730/what-is-the-difference-between-one-and-first

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
    if user:
        return user
    return None
```

Applying the `.first()` executes the query, instead of storing the Query object
it will return only the first result.

`.all()` returns all

edit:

or you could use `user = User.query.get(user_id)` assuming `user_id` is defined as PK

In your Login Function it should be

```
  user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password) == True:
        login_user(user)
```

Now user references a real User object, as opposed to a stored query. you cannot access a User Object attribute (password) from a Query Object

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. I read about .first() and .all() but didn't think they would have changed anything as the query would be the same. I wasn't aware it .first() would run the query rather than store the object! Big help!

Comment: There's no need to check `if user` in your `user_loader`, `first()` returns `None` if the query doesn't yield any results.

Comment: I am learning sqlalchemy as well.  Of course you would only get the OBJECT referencing the query without first().  Thank you so much.  You saved me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't miss .first() or .all() after the SQLQLCHAMY ORM query.

This is cause of such error always.

Comment: More detail needs to be provided as to why that .first() and .all() does.